# Pythonを使いGitHub上のissueを取得して自分のPCに保存するには？

Tags: python, github

Pythonを使ってGitHub上のアプリのissueを取得してそれを自分のPCに保存したいのですが、そのコードをどう書いたらいいのかわかりません。公式のドキュメントをみてもいまいち理解ができませんでした。
どなたかコードを教えていただければ幸いです。

Comment: [PyGithub 1.53](https://pypi.org/project/PyGithub/)というモジュールがあって、[Get list of open issues](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Repository.html#get-list-of-open-issues)に例が出ているので試してみてはどうでしょう？ 関連情報はこちら。[get_issues(...)](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Repository.html?highlight=get_issues#github.Repository.Repository.get_issues), [classgithub.PaginatedList.PaginatedList](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/utilities.html#github.PaginatedList.PaginatedList), [classgithub.Issue.Issue](https://pygithub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/github_objects/Issue.html)